# RoR, Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm stuck at Chapter 7 in the Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial.

My routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"
  resources :users
  root  'static_pages#home'
  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get'
  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help',    via: 'get'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about',   via: 'get'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact', via: 'get'
end
```

My spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }
    let(:submit) { "Sign up" }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "with invalid information" do
    it "should not create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
    end
  end

  describe "with valid information" do
    before do
      fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
      fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
      fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
      fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
    end

    it "should create a user" do
      expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
    end
  end
end
```

My app/views/users/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

And when I try to run test I get this:

```
gvyntyk@gvyntyk-r60:~/rails_projects/sample_app$ bundle exec rspec spec/
...............FF......................

Failures:

  1) User pages with invalid information should not create a user
     Failure/Error: expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `submit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_3:0xad40120>
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages with valid information should create a user
     Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find field "Name"
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.54 seconds
39 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:26 # User pages with invalid information should not create a user
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:39 # User pages with valid information should create a user
```

Can someone please explain why this test is failing?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `click_button :submit`?

Comment: Excuse me... what do you mean? Edit expect { click_button submit } on expect { click_button :submit }?

Comment: I mean you are trying to execute undefined `submit` method, while you should pass a symbol `:submit`

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand where I mistook. Now button submit ("Create my account") works correctly, but doesn't pass test.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are at a point on the chapter where the tests should pass. There are some tests that are not supposed to pass after you change the code.
Also, your second error seems to be an authentication issue. Unable to find field "Name"  could mean that at the time that this test is running the user should have have sign_up. I am not quite sure on the fragment you posted, but make sure that all of your indentation is correct and your 'ends' are closing in the right place. The way you have the code right now it does not look like you are signing up before executing the "with valid information". Try placing the "end" of the   describe "signup page" do, at the very bottom before the "end" of the "describe "User pages" do" block.

Comment: I assumed it... Tests passed before Successful signups.

Answer (score 0):

From `click_button` docs:

> Finds a button by id, text, value or title and clicks it.

So you can supply button value to `click_button` method. Instead of:

```
expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

it should be:

```
expect { click_button 'Create my account' }.not_to change(User, :count)
```

And you receive this error:

```
Failure/Error: fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find field "Name"
```

Because you forgot to `visit signup_path` in both:

```
describe "with invalid information" do
```

and

```
describe "with valid information" do
```

blocks.